# Optimising query - user subscriptions in 1 database, 3-level data in another. Finding top level where user has subscriptions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an application which stores a hierarchical list of filters which a user can subscribe/unsubscribe from.

There are 2 databases involved:

1. `db1`: Stores the hierarchical list
2. `db2`: Stores the user's subscription preferences

Both databases are on the same server.

The hierarchical list (in `db1`) is composed of 3 tables as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE regulations;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE groups;
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| regulation_id | int(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE filters;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_id | int(4) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So the hierarchy is:

- `regulations`

  - `groups` (foreign key: `regulation_id`)

    - `filters` (foreign key: `group_id`)

The user is subscribed to 1 or more `filters.id`. These are stored in a separate database (database name: `db2`) where the `f_id` field corresponds to `filters.id`. The table structure is as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE tbl_alerts;
+--------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tbl_id | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| u_id   | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to know which `regulations.name` the user has subscriptions for.

The way in which I've done this is to select all of the `f_id` in `tbl_alerts` (assuming a user ID of 123, represented by `u_id`), e.g.

```
SELECT f_id FROM tbl_alerts WHERE u_id = 123;
```

And then use this in an `IN` condition as follows:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(db1.regulations.`name`)
FROM
db1.groups
JOIN db1.regulations
ON db1.groups.regulation_id = db1.regulations.id 
JOIN db1.filters
ON db1.filters.group_id = db1.groups.id
WHERE db1.filters.`id` IN (
    SELECT f_id FROM db2.tbl_alerts WHERE u_id = 123 
)
```

Is there a more optimal way to write this?

Using 5.5.60-MariaDB

Comment: Is there any particular reason to store filter-user combination table in another database ? Normally, all the tables are stored in the same database only.

Comment: Historically they have been stored in 2 separate databases as they were used primarily by different applications. It can't be changed now as those legacy apps are still running. Does this change the answer in any case? We can do a cross-database join as demonstrated by the query I've posted for how I'm doing things now. So I don't think that has any bearing on the answer, unless you think otherwise?

Comment: The notation `db.tbl` can be used anywhere you just a table name.  That is, the fact that two databases are involved does not matter except in that syntax detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following "Cross-Database" Join query:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT db1.regulations.name
FROM
  db1.groups
JOIN db1.regulations
  ON db1.groups.regulation_id = db1.regulations.id 
JOIN db1.filters
  ON db1.filters.group_id = db1.groups.id 
JOIN db2.tbl_alerts 
  ON db2.tbl_alerts.f_id = db1.filters.id 
WHERE db2.tbl_alerts.u_id = 123
```

Note that `DISTINCT` keyword is not a function, so parentheses are unnecessary. Now, regarding the performance part, you will need to benchmark between your current set of queries, versus this single query.